# register_kprobe returns EINVAL (-22) error for instructions involving rip

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module, kprobe

I am trying to insert probes at different instructions with kprobes in function of kernel module.

But register_kprobe is returning EINVAL(-22) error for 0xffffffffa33c1085 instruction addresses and 0xffffffffa33c109b from below assembly code (it passes for all other instruction addresses).

Instructions giving errors:

```
0xffffffffa33c1085 <test_increment+5>:  mov    0x21bd(%rip),%eax        # 0xffffffffa33c3248
0xffffffffa33c109b <test_increment+27>: mov    %esi,0x21a7(%rip)        # 0xffffffffa33c3248
```

Observed that both these instructions use rip register. Tried with functions of other modules, observed same error with instructions which use rip register.

Why is register_kprobe failing ? does it have any constraints involving rip ?  Any help is appreciated.

System has kernel 3.10.0-514 on x86_64 installed.

kprobe function:

```
kp = kzalloc(sizeof(struct kprobe), GFP_KERNEL);
kp->post_handler = exit_func;
kp->pre_handler = entry_func;
kp->addr = sym_addr;
atomic_set(&pcount, 0);
ret = register_kprobe(kp);
if ( ret != 0 ) {
    printk(KERN_INFO "register_kprobe returned %d for %s\n", ret, str);
    kfree(kp);
    kp=NULL;
    return ret;
}
```

probed function:

```
int race=0;
void test_increment()
{
    race++;
    printk(KERN_INFO "VALUE=%d\n",race);
    return;
}
```

assembly code:

```
crash> dis -l test_increment
0xffffffffa33c1080 <test_increment>:    nopl   0x0(%rax,%rax,1) [FTRACE NOP]
0xffffffffa33c1085 <test_increment+5>:  mov    0x21bd(%rip),%eax        # 0xffffffffa33c3248
0xffffffffa33c108b <test_increment+11>: push   %rbp
0xffffffffa33c108c <test_increment+12>: mov    $0xffffffffa33c2024,%rdi
0xffffffffa33c1093 <test_increment+19>: mov    %rsp,%rbp
0xffffffffa33c1096 <test_increment+22>: lea    0x1(%rax),%esi
0xffffffffa33c1099 <test_increment+25>: xor    %eax,%eax
0xffffffffa33c109b <test_increment+27>: mov    %esi,0x21a7(%rip)        # 0xffffffffa33c3248
0xffffffffa33c10a1 <test_increment+33>: callq  0xffffffff81659552 <printk>
0xffffffffa33c10a6 <test_increment+38>: pop    %rbp
0xffffffffa33c10a7 <test_increment+39>: retq
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, register_kprobe does have limitations with instructions invoving rip relative addressing for x86_64.

Here is snippet of __copy_instruction function code causing error (register_kprobe -> prepare_kprobe -> arch_prepare_kprobe -> arch_copy_kprobe -> __copy_instruction )

```
#ifdef CONFIG_X86_64
    if (insn_rip_relative(&insn)) {
        s64 newdisp;
        u8 *disp;
        kernel_insn_init(&insn, dest);
        insn_get_displacement(&insn);
        /*
         * The copied instruction uses the %rip-relative addressing
         * mode.  Adjust the displacement for the difference between
         * the original location of this instruction and the location
         * of the copy that will actually be run.  The tricky bit here
         * is making sure that the sign extension happens correctly in
         * this calculation, since we need a signed 32-bit result to
         * be sign-extended to 64 bits when it's added to the %rip
         * value and yield the same 64-bit result that the sign-
         * extension of the original signed 32-bit displacement would
         * have given.
         */
        newdisp = (u8 *) src + (s64) insn.displacement.value - (u8 *) dest;
        if ((s64) (s32) newdisp != newdisp) {
            pr_err("Kprobes error: new displacement does not fit into s32 (%llx)\n", newdisp);
            pr_err("\tSrc: %p, Dest: %p, old disp: %x\n", src, dest, insn.displacement.value);
            return 0;
        }
        disp = (u8 *) dest + insn_offset_displacement(&insn);
        *(s32 *) disp = (s32) newdisp;
    }
#endif
```

http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v3.10/ident/__copy_instruction

A new displacement value is calculated based new instruction address (where orig insn is copied). If that value doesn't fit in 32 bit, it returns 0 which results in EINVAL error. Hence the failure.

As a workaround, we can set kprobe handler post previous instruction or pre next instruction based on need (works for me).

Comment: Yes, I have stumbled upon this problem some time ago and sent a patch to fix it: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=c80e5c0c23ce2282476fdc64c4b5e3d3a40723fd. The patch made it into kernel 4.1. I don't remember if any stable kernels picked it.